# Problems When fetching relation data with eagerload laravel 9

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem when Eager Loading a data which is already has one to many relationship and the error like code bellow

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'media_categories.foto_id' in 'where clause'

select * from `media_categories` where `media_categories`.`foto_id` in (2)
```

this error appear when i try to eagerload the media_category data from FotoController, And why its demanding foto_id?

this is my controller

```
$foto = Foto::with('mediaCategory','user')->where('id', $request->id)->first();

    return Inertia::render('Foto/DetailFoto', [
        'foto' => $foto
    ]);
```

and this is my table scheme

this is my fotos table

```
   Schema::create('fotos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedInteger('media_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->decimal('price');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('folder');
        $table->smallInteger('pcs');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

this is my media_categories table

```
    Schema::create('media_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

and this is my relationship at foto model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->BelongsTo(User::class);
}
public function mediaCategory(){
    return $this->HasMany(MediaCategory::class);
}
```

this my media_category model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->BelongsTo(User::class);
}
public function foto(){
    return $this->BelongsTo(Foto::class);
}
```

Comment: The query is correct... You need to explain what are you expecting, as we do not know what schema you expect to have... HasMany is saying that Foto (should be Photo) has many MediaCategory, that means that MediaCategory has foto_id as a column... But you don't have it in your schema, so how are you expecting to connect Foto with MediaCategory?

Comment: i just want to load the media_category data which is has relations with the foto

Comment: lets say in foto i have a media_id which is foreign key and i want to retrieve the data of foto with the media based on the relations @matiaslauriti this is my first time to use relations on model so im confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the relationship as HasMany in the Foto model, but it should be BelongsTo instead

```
public function mediaCategory(){
    return $this->belongsTo(MediaCategory::class, 'media_id');
}
```